# How can I run Flask/Python3.x over SSL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, flask

When I load the page the browser says "This site can’t be reached"

My code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def route1():
  return f'--- request received ----'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # https://www.name-of-my-domain.com
    app.run(port='8443', ssl_context=('./mydir/name-of-my-domain.com.crt', './mydir/private.key'))
```

I also tried:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def route1():
    return f'--- request received ----'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # https://www.name-of-my-domain.com
    run_simple('https://www.name-of-my-domain.com/', 8443, app, ssl_context=('./mydir/name-of-my-domain.com.crt', './mydir/private.key'))
```

and also:

```
import ssl
# ... as before for app ...
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.load_cert_chain('./mydir/name-of-my-domain.com.crt', './mydir/private.key')
run_simple('https://www.name-of-my-domain.com/', 8443, app, ssl_context=context)
```

but for the last two I get an error when I run the file:

```
File "bot.py", line 38, in <module>
    run_simple('https://www.name-of-my-domain.com', 8443, app, ssl_context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1052, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1005, in inner
    fd=fd,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 863, in make_server
    host, port, app, request_handler, passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 740, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, handler)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 456, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/server.py", line 136, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 470, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: I would use nginx to manage the ssl configuration and the redirect with a [reverse proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) in order not to worry about that. Also, you'll be able to find way more documentation that for ssl flask.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it putting as host **'0.0.0.0'**, and it worked with all three code examples ('127.0.0.1' did't work though)